# A mistake at Matlab programming - Varying Results from similar blocks of code

Tags: matlab, pointers, if-statement, vector, encoding

Why cant i get the same results from the 1st and 2nd coding? Where is my mistake? 
I re-did the first block of code, shown in the 2nd block below. But I can't find where the error is:

1)

```
V = [5,17,-3,8,0,-7,12,15,20,-6,6,4,-7,16];

a=length(V);

for k=1:a

    if V(k)>0 && (rem(V(k),3)==0 || rem(V(k),5)==0)

        V(k)=2*V(k);

        elseif -5 < V(k) < 0

            V(k)=V(k)^3;

    end

  end
```

2)

```
V = [5,17,-3,8,0,-7,12,15,20,-6,6,4,-7,16];

a=length(V);

for k=1:a

    b=V(k);

    if b>0 &&(rem(b,3)==0 || rem(b,5))==0

        b=2*b;

        elseif -5 < b < 0

            b=b^3;

    end

  end
```

Comment: b is not pointer to V(k) so when you do b=2*b it does not change the original V(k)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes in your code:

1. **Syntactic**: You have placed `==0` outside the parenthesis when checking the `if` condition. i.e. `(rem(b,3)==0 || rem(b,5)) ==0` is not the same as `(rem(b,3)==0 || rem(b,5)==0)` in the first part of the code.

   1. *In the later case*, you are checking if b is a multiple of 3 OR a multiple of 5, which is, I believe, what you want?
   2. However, *in the former case*, you are checking if b is a multiple of 5 AND not a multiple of 3.
2. **Logical**: You are assuming that the assignment operator `b=V(k)` is passing the reference to the kth-index element in the vector `V` to `b`, however, Matlab is only `pass-by-value`. So once you have passed the value of `V(k)` to `b`, any changes made to `b` will not affect `V(k)` because `b` is NOT pointing to `V(k)`. Thus, at the end of the loop, `b` would just contain the last element of `V`, i.e. `V(length(V))`, modified by the `if-elseif` clause.

You may refer to [Working with Pointers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/working-with-pointers.html) section on the Mathworks website to find out more about how to work with pointers if this is indeed what you want.

Comment: Aw. Thank you very much I got it now. I appreciate your help a lot